# Help with complex algebra on a pizza problem

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

The question goes as follows:

8 mushrooms are evenly and symmetrically placed on a pizza surface. The pizza can be modelled on the argand diagram with a radius of $6$ cm. The first mushroom (M1), is placed on the coordinates: $3\sqrt{3}+3i$. Find the other mushrooms and find a possible complex equation where the solutions of it would give the positions of the 8 mushrooms.

My attempt:

Since they are evenly split out, then I would divide $2\pi$ by $8$, and add the value until I reach M1 again to get the position of the $7$ other mushrooms. I converted the position of M1 into polar form getting; $6\cdot\operatorname{cis}(\frac{\pi}{6})$ and did what I said above. I need help with the second part. See, the number of solutions is $8$ so the highest degree must equal $8$, however it would be very complex to multiply all the $8$ solutions by hand to obtain the equation.

Comment: $(x-2)(x-1)=0$ is just as much an equation as $x^2-3x+2=0$ is. Why do you need to multiply anything?

Comment: @DavidK I do not understand, I would need to multiply the solutions to get the equation

Comment: Is $(x-2)(x-1)=0$, written **exactly like that** with no further work performed on it, an equation, or is it not? If you say it is not an equation, why do you say that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unfamiliar with the *cis* notation, so I will stick with $e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta).$

The $8$ roots of

$$~z^8 = re^{i\alpha} ~: ~r \in \Bbb{R^+} \tag1 $$

are given by

$$z = r^{(1/8)}e^{i[(\alpha/8) + (2k\pi/8)]} : k \in \{0,1,\cdots, 7\}.\tag2 $$

The reason for this is:

- $\displaystyle \left[r^{(1/8)}e^{i(\alpha/8)}\right]^8 = re^{i\alpha}.$
- $\displaystyle \left[e^{i(2k\pi/8)}\right]^8 = 1 ~: ~k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,7\}.$

What this means is that if you have any root $se^{i\theta}$, of the equation in (1) above, then using (2) above, the other $7$ roots to the equation in (1) above will be given by

$$se^{i[\theta + (2k\pi/8)]} ~: ~k \in \{1,2,\cdots,7\}. \tag3 $$

In the present problem, you are given (in effect) that 
$s = 6e^{i\pi/6}.$

So, using (3) above, the other $7$ locations are

$$6e^{i[(\pi/6) + (2k\pi/8)]} ~: ~k \in \{1,2,\cdots,7\}. \tag4 $$

Furthermore, per (1) and (2) above, $s = 6e^{i\pi/6}$ is a root of

$$z^8 = 6^8 e^{i(8\pi/6)}. \tag5 $$

---

This begs the question, why am I forcing the equation $z^8 = s^8?$

Answer:
Because this forces all $8$ *roots* to be equally spaced apart in *degrees*, with each of the roots being the same distance from the center of the pizza.

Comment: $\mathrm{cis}\,\theta$  is $\cos\theta + i \sin \theta$.

Comment: @soupless I suspected that.  However, I am more comfortable expressing $~\displaystyle \left[e^{i\theta}\right]^8$ than I would be, trying to express $\displaystyle \left[\text{cis}(\theta)\right]^8.$

Answer (score 0):

Recall how [complex number multiplication in polar form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Multiplication_and_division_in_polar_form) behaves: multiplying a complex number by $e^{i \theta} = \operatorname{cis}(\theta) = \cos \theta + i \, \sin \theta$ rotates that number by $\theta$ in the complex plane.

Thus, we can rotate any complex number by one eight turn, by $360°/8 = 45°$ ($2 \pi / 8 = \pi / 4$ radians), by multiplying it by complex number
$$r = e^{i \, \pi / 4} = \operatorname{cis}(45°) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} + i \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$$
and rotating
$$z = 3 \sqrt{3} + 3 i$$
around the origin in the complex plane yields
$$z_k = r^k z = \left(\operatorname{cis}(45°)\right)^k \left( 3\sqrt{3} + 3 i \right), \quad k = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7$$
noting that we can calculate each successive result by multiplying the previous one by $r$, thus requiring just one complex multiplication per result: $z_0 = z$, $z_1 = r z_0$, $z_2 = r z_1$, and so on.

We can reduce the work needed by noting that $\operatorname{cis}(2 \cdot 45°) = \operatorname{cis}(90°) = i$ and $\operatorname{cis}(4 \cdot 45°) = \operatorname{cis}(180°) = -1$.  This means that $z_2 = i z_0 = i z$, $z_4 = -z_0 = -z$, $z_6 = -i z$:
$$\begin{array}{rll}
z = & z_0 = ~ ~ ~ 3 \sqrt{3} + 3 i & \approx +5.196152 + 3.000000 i \\
~ & z_2 = -3 + 3 \sqrt{3} i & \approx -3.000000 + 5.196152 i \\
~ & z_4 = -3 \sqrt{3} - 3 i & \approx -5.196152 - 3.000000 i \\
~ & z_6 = ~ ~ ~ 3 - 3 \sqrt{3} i & \approx +3.000000 - 5.196152 i \\
\end{array}$$
Because
$$z_1 = r z = \left(\frac{1}{sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} i \right) \left( 3\sqrt{3} + 3 i \right) = \frac{3 \sqrt{3} - 3}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{3 \sqrt{3} + 3}{\sqrt{2}}$$
and $z_3 = i z_1$, $z_5 = -z_1$, $z_7 = -i z_1$, we have
$$\begin{array}{ll}
z_1 = \displaystyle \frac{3 \sqrt{3} - 3}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{3 \sqrt{3} + 3}{\sqrt{2}} i & \approx +1.552914 + 5.795555 i \\
z_3 = \displaystyle \frac{-3 \sqrt{3} - 3}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{3 \sqrt{3} - 3}{\sqrt{2}} i & \approx -5.795555 + 1.552914 i \\
z_5 = \displaystyle \frac{-3 \sqrt{3} + 3}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{-3 \sqrt{3} - 3}{\sqrt{2}} i & \approx -1.552914 - 5.795555 i \\
z_7 = \displaystyle \frac{3 \sqrt{3} + 3}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{-3 \sqrt{3} + 3}{\sqrt{2}} i & \approx +5.795555 - 1.552914 i \\
\end{array}$$

---

If the polar form of $z$ is known –– here, $z = 6 e^{i \pi / 6} = 6 \operatorname{cis}\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) = 6\operatorname{cis}(180°/6) = 6 \operatorname{cis}(30°)$ ––, we can simply add the rotation ($45° = \pi/4 = 3 \pi/12$ in radians) to the phase; i.e.
$$\begin{aligned}
z = z_0 &= 6 \operatorname{cis}\left(\frac{2 \pi}{12}\right) = 6 \operatorname{cis}\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) \\
z_1 &= 6 \operatorname{cis}\left(\frac{5 \pi}{12}\right) \\
z_2 &= 6 \operatorname{cis}\left(\frac{8 \pi}{12}\right) = 6 \operatorname{cis}\left(\frac{2 \pi}{3}\right) \\
z_3 &= 6 \operatorname{cis}\left(\frac{11 \pi}{12}\right) \\
z_4 &= 6 \operatorname{cis}\left(\frac{14 \pi}{12}\right) = 6 \operatorname{cis}\left(\frac{7 \pi}{6}\right) \\
z_5 &= 6 \operatorname{cis}\left(\frac{17 \pi}{12}\right) \\
z_6 &= 6 \operatorname{cis}\left(\frac{20 \pi}{12}\right) = 6 \operatorname{cis}\left(\frac{5 \pi}{3}\right) \\
z_7 &= 6 \operatorname{cis}\left(\frac{23 \pi}{12}\right) \\
\end{aligned}$$
These do match exactly the earlier $z_0$ through $z_8$ shown above, but unless you have a table of exact sine and cosine values (or a computer algebra system like Maxima, SageMath, Maple, for example), it can be very difficult to convert the above back to exact Cartesian complex form.

If one *needs* the exact values in Cartesian form, one should probably use the earlier rotate-via-multiplication approach; if not, or the conversion back to Cartesian complex form is not a problem, then this latter approach should prove less work.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question asks for a complex equation, it is not necessarily a complex polynomial. Hence, we can just start with the equation $$\exp\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n} i\right) = 1, \qquad k = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, n - 1$$ which gives the $n$th roots of unity. We also know that $$\exp\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n} i\right) = \cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right) + i \sin\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n} i\right).$$

We can just add an arbitrary $\theta$ to the arguments, which gives us $$\exp\left(\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}+\theta\right) i\right) = \cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n} + \theta\right) + i \sin\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n} + \theta\right).$$

Since we are to find eight roots, $n$ must be $8$.

---

We want the given value, $3\sqrt{3} + 3i$ to be the first root. You converted this already to $6\,\mathrm{cis}(\frac{\pi}{6})$. This means that we have to solve the equation $$\frac{2(0)\pi}{8} + \theta = \frac{\pi}{6}$$ which simplifies to $$\theta = \frac{\pi}{6}$$.

We are then left with the equation $$\exp\left(\left(\frac{2k\pi}{8} + \frac{\pi}{6}\right)i\right) = 1$$ which gives the desired solutions. If you don't want this method, you can get all the eighth roots of unity $\{0, \pi/4, \pi/2, 3\pi/4, \pi, 5\pi/4, 3\pi/2, 7\pi/4\}$, add each of them by $\pi/6$ $(\{\pi/6, 2\pi/3, 11\pi/12, 7\pi/6, 17\pi/12, 5\pi/3, 23\pi/12\})$, and use these as the roots to get the polynomial: $$(z - \pi/6)(z - 2\pi/3)(z - 11\pi/12)(z - 7\pi/6)(z - 17\pi/12)(z - 5\pi/3)(z - 23\pi/12) = 0$$